# Selenium Webdriver -- No such Element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to login into Sears.com using `Selenium` `webdriver.clicked` on Sign in link-->login form opens.

But unable to locate the text box element inside the login form. The login form is inside an iframe (`frame Name =easyXDM_default5914_provider`).This iframe is inside div (id=modaliframe)

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//iframe[@id='easyXDM_default5914_provider']")));
driver.switchTo().activeElement();
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("xxx@gmail.com");
```

**Getting below exception in my console:**

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"id","selector":"email"}

Comment: Why do you `switchTo().activeElement()`? Also the IFRAME ID seems to change, so try `.//iframe[starts-with(@name, 'easyXDM_')]`

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code.

```
driver.get("http://www.sears.com/");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='header-shop-your-way-partner']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='open-sign-in-form']/span[2]")).click();
driver.switchTo().frame("registration-form-iframe");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys("abcd@gmail.com");
Thread.sleep(3000);
```